# A delve into extraordinary chess problems: Selfmate 1

Tags: chess

[This series continues from a harder puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88999/a-delve-into-extraordinary-chess-problems-self-stalemate-2) and continues in [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89459/a-delve-into-extraordinary-chess-problems-selfmate-2)]

Here we have an easier but still interesting selfmate in 5.

This is a puzzle by A. Rubin found in *The Book of Extraordinary Chess Puzzles*:

> [image: selfmate 1]
>
> From the book: "In a 'selfmate' problem White plays to force Black to checkmate him - a sort of chess suicide. In the diagram above, White has his king nicely trapped in the bottom right-hand corner, but still has to find a way of forcing Black to deliver the mate. Selfmate in five.

[Here is an interactive board for you to play on](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/2B5/p2Q4/1P6/2P5/3P2n1/4P1Pk/5Pp1/6K1_w_-_-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is it as simple as

> 1. Ba6 forcing axb6
>  2. Bb5 bxc5
>  3. Bc4 bxd4
>  4. Bd3 bxe3
>  5. Be2 bxf2#

Taking advantage of the fact

> that black's knight can't move (pinned by the queen) and blacks king can't move.

Comment: It certainly is! It's an intro into the genre. Next one will be harder. Also, have a go at the 2nd self-stalemate. It's very good.

Comment: @DrXorile i've been having a go at it.  I have nothing to show yet for it but a splitting headache.