# A delve into extraordinary chess problems: Selfmate 2

Tags: chess

(Continuing the series from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89366/a-delve-into-extraordinary-chess-problems-selfmate-1))

Here is a second **selfmate** puzzle (also relatively easy, but beware the traps!). It is by C. R. Flood from 1967, and is puzzle 81 in *The Book of Extraordinary Chess Puzzles*:

> [image: selfmate 2]
>
> White to play and selfmate in three.
>   As a reminder: "In a 'selfmate' problem White plays to force Black to checkmate him - a sort of chess suicide."

[Here is an analysis board for you to play around with](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/8/2p5/6pp/2R3pk/2R5/2P3PK/6PP/8_w_-_-).

Comment: I would like to see a selfmade selfmate problem in the future :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work

> 1. Ra4, c6
>  2. Rca5, c5
>  3. c4, g4

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

> 1.Ra4 c6
>  2.Rca5 c5
>  3.c4 g4#

Comment: Congratulations. However, @Jens got there first. Welcome to Puzzling.SE

Answer (score 0):

This version of Jens answer gives black the option of capturing a piece as well as checkmating.

> 1. Rb4, c6
>  2. Rcb5, c5
>  3. c4, g4

Comment: Black can just play 3... cxb4 and then it's not mate ...